# Where should the "unselect/unclear filter" icon go?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design

I am designing a major component of my soon-to-be website: the listings header where I provide users a magnifying glass to filter out records according to the Loading/Delivery/Tag options trio.  (I don't mean the funnel filter in the upper right corner).

[image: Listings header]

My issue is with where to position a Reset option.

If I don't have such a reset option it will make it more difficult for the end user to reset the list and he/she would be more than likely to hit the browser's back button to return to the last all-records-shown list.

That's the kind of behavior I want to avoid. So, where should that icon go? What would be the best position for it?

Comment: Might not a user expect a magnifying glass button to reveal a search function?

Answer (score 1):

I would add a text hyperlink above the first row of results that reads "Clear Filtered Results".  This serves two purposes: it allows the user to clear the results and reminds them that the results being shown are currently under the effect of a filter.  Note that this hyperlink text only appears after a filter has been applied.  It does not show when the page is first loaded.

I also agree with Shreyas that the filter/funnel icon seems out of place since it looks like you have 4 different filtering dropdowns but the icon is only next to one of them.  Might as well get rid of the icon as the dropdowns seem self-explanatory.

I tried adding it to your design and re-arranging the buttons and drop downs so the balance is a little better.

[image: Edited]

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Samantha. I think you just summed up the best solution! I will reply yours and Shreya's suggestion to my IT team. Cheers for you both!!

Comment: The problem with this design is that it takes a lot of vertical real estate away from the focus of the page, the grid. I agree with the text based approach

Answer (score 0):

For negative/destructive actions like "Delete", "Clear", "Reset", "Remove", it is preferable to use links, text buttons or icon+text buttons.

[image: reset]

Also, I am not exactly sure what the funnel icon on top is supposed to represent if the 3 drop downs below are used for filtering the search results. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Dear Shreyas, the funnel filter is actually a primary filter for the "mode of transport" (land, sea, or air cargo). Your reset link is a great solution. However, looking at all your replies, I guess Samantha has just provided what best appeals to me in terms of usability!